Suppressing Azure Alert for specific period and auto re-activate it after the period
Is there any way to suppress Azure alerts for specific time period and it should be auto enabled after specific time which is suppressed before?
Looking for a automated way.

There is no direct way to achieve this in Azure, but you can automate this requirement by using an Azure Automation Account with PowerShell code.

Azure Powerautomate can help here?

Powerautomate does not allow us to execute PowerShell code. Automation account is a simple method.

If you are okay, I will post a detailed solution using an automation account.

currently we are having Azuredevops server pipeline automation  with ARM templates to create these LAW rules over  a big list of items. its a self service approach for our developers  and they can update the alert rules queries and thresholds as they require.
So, will this possible to have a pipeline based solution with automation accounts to manage the app tea with their suppression period ? Note: We are using onprem Azuredevops server and not azuredevops service, so will this can communicate to azure automation account ?

If you are using on-prem Azuredevops server and want to connect to azure automation account, you can use Azure P2S VPN.

Ok.. Great.. pls add the automation account related solution to the answer.

You can also create alert processing rule for your requirement, check this helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-processing-rules?tabs=portal and Configure an alert processing rule


Suppressing Azure Alert for specific period and auto re-activate it after the period

You can use alert processing rule to suppress the alerts for specific period of time , follow the MS DOC for more details.
Alternatively, you can use an Azure Automation account with a PowerShell script; here are the detailed steps.
In the script, specify the time period for which the alert should be suppressed. In my case, I have given a 60-minute time frame to re-enable the alert and schedule your automation to run on a specific date and time.

Note: Make sure to assign the required role to Azure identity.

Connect-AzAccount -Identity

Set-AzContext -Subscription "SUB_ID"

$ResourceGroupName = "Automation_RG"
$AlertRuleName = "Demo-Rule"
$DisableDurationInMinutes = 60

try {
    Write-Output "Disabling the alert rule '$AlertRuleName'..."

    Update-AzActivityLogAlert -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $AlertRuleName -Enabled $false

    Write-Output "Alert rule '$AlertRuleName' is disabled."
}
catch {
    Write-Error "Failed to disable alert rule '$AlertRuleName': $_"
    exit
}


$waitTime = $DisableDurationInMinutes * 60
Write-Output "Waiting for $DisableDurationInMinutes minutes before re-enabling the alert rule..."
Start-Sleep -Seconds $waitTime

try {
    Write-Output "Re-enabling the alert rule '$AlertRuleName'..."
    Update-AzActivityLogAlert -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $AlertRuleName -Enabled $true
    Write-Output "Alert rule '$AlertRuleName' is re-enabled."
}
catch {
    Write-Error "Failed to re-enable alert rule '$AlertRuleName': $_"
}

Output:

After running the script, azure alert rule has been disabled and it will be enabled after 60mns.


is there any way to pass aset of alert rules with different suppression period each, dynamically to the automation account.? What we are looking is, the end developers can suppress the alert rules for specific period , when they are working on certain fixes and that should be approved by the platform Administrators.

If you can specify a time period in the script for when they want to suppress the alert.so that alerts will stop after a certain time period.You can also schedule an automation account.

But this is again a manual task and can we make a set of alert rules with diffrent suppression period together?

You just specify the time period in the script for how long you want to suppress the alert, and schedule the automation account to start the activity at the desired time. The automation account will run at that time and wait for the specified period in the script, automatically enabling it afterward. Everything runs automatically without requiring manual intervention.
